# How to print Lao to thermal printer using bluetooth_thermal_printer library by Flutter

Tags: flutter

With this library it is fine printing A-Z English, when i change ticket.text"ABC" to ticket.text"ສະບາຍດີ" in Lao language -> then i got an error as screenshot below, there is other article i have been visited but since those seems to be high level explanation to me 'i still blind how does that work', it would be more informative if solution comes with example project, thanks in advance for your support here - i believe there is not only me stuck with this and i don't believe it is not possible to do that!

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59475607/how-to-print-asian-languages-to-a-thermal-printer-from-flutter)

[image]

Comment: did you solve it

Comment: By work around, i make pdf file then convert to image and print it as an image