# EOS thermal printer does not print Arabic characters properly when using Flutter framework

Tags: html, flutter, dart, printing

**Context:**

I have an EOS thermal printer, but it does not print Arabic characters properly like in this image below:

[image: Incorrect Arabic encoding]

As you can see, the Arabic text is printed incorrectly and from Left-to-Right (LTR), (it should be Right-to-Left - RTL).

*Note*: You can clearly see the English text is printed perfectly at the end of the page.

**Question:**

How can I print Arabic text the right way in flutter?

**Additional Info:**

Flutter version: 2.5.3 (Stable)

Package Used: [escpos](https://pub.dev/packages/escpos)

Tested on multiple Android devices running Android version (8, 9 ,10)

Comment: Check my answer here.
It's the only thing that worked for me.
[thermal print arabic characters correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72467511/7484297)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first I have used the esc_pos package and it didn't work.
In the end, I've used the *printing package* to print an Arabic invoice and it works fine, and the explanation below

> This is the full code to use the printing package.
> first, create a class to pass the parameters to it(the parameters that you need to print) in my case 4 required param.

```
class HtmlGeneratorParamsAccount {
  final String daybet, payable, balance;
  final List<AccountStatmentModel> list;

  HtmlGeneratorParamsAccount({
    required this.daybet,
    required this.payable,
    required this.balance,
    required this.list,
  });
}

String generateHtmlA(HtmlGeneratorParamsAccount p) {
  String items = '''
    ''';

  for (var i = 0; i < p.list.length; i++) {
    DateFormat datee = DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd', 'en');
    DateTime forFormat = p.list[i].date;
    final String formatted = datee.format(forFormat);
    double amount = p.list[i].debitAmount + p.list[i].payableAmount;
    items += '''<tr class = "item">''';

    items += '''<td>${p.list[i].description}</td>''';
    items += '''<td>${formatted}</td>''';
    items += '''<td>${p.list[i].opName}</td>''';
    items += '''<td>${double.parse(amount.toStringAsFixed(1))}</td>''';
    items += '''</tr>''';
  }
  var pay = double.parse(p.payable).toStringAsFixed(1);
  var day = double.parse(p.daybet).toStringAsFixed(1);
  var html = """
```

> then you need to use HTML to build the body of your invoice(shape)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>

      .invoice-box {
        max-width:1000px;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 8px;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        font-size: 8px;
        line-height: 24px;
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #555;
      }
        .invoice-box table {
        width: 100%;
        line-height: inherit;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .invoice-box table td {
        padding: 10px;
        vertical-align: top;
      }
 
      .invoice-box table tr.top table td {
        padding-bottom: 5px;
      }

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.column {
  float: right;
  width:23%;
  
  padding: 16px;
 
}
.header{
text-align:center;
}


.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2 class="header">كشف حساب</h2>
<h3 class="header">بيانات الزبون</h3>
<table>
<tr>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" >
    <h4>المبلغ</h4>
    <p></p>
  </div>
 
  <div class="column" >

    <h4>نوع العملية</h4>
    
  </div>

  <div class="column" >
    <h4>تاريخ</h4>
   
  </div>
  <div class="column" >
    <h4>وصف</h4>
    
  </div>
</div>
</tr>
$items
</table>
<div>
<p class="header">------------------------</p>
<p class="header">:مجموع ${day}</p>
<p class="header">:مجموع $pay</p>
<p class="header">:المبلغ ${p.balance}</p>
<p>---</p>
<p>--</p>
<p>-</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>""";
  return html;

'''
```

create a function

> when you need to use it (in button for example)

printDoc(HtmlGeneratorParamsAccount params) async {

```
await Printing.layoutPdf(
  onLayout: (format) async => await Printing.convertHtml(
    format: format,
    html: generateHtmlA(params),
  ),
);
```

}
now we will use the printDoc function inside IconButton

> the params is the class we've made in the beginning, and we will  pass the required parameters

```
 IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            HtmlGeneratorParamsAccount params=
                HtmlGeneratorParamsAccount(
              list: list,
              payable: payableAmount.toString(),
              daybet: debitTxt.toString(),
              balance: balance.toString(),
            );
            printDoc(params);
          },
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.print,
          )),
```

Comment: how about mobile ?

Answer (score 2):

you can check this

this repo use 3 laiblary

secreenshot to convert widget to image
and image library to convert it to uint8
and pos pront to print it as u love to show

u can check it from [here](https://github.com/blackangiliq/flutter_pos_printer_spport_arabic)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Flutter framework and your EOS thermal printer is not printing Arabic characters correctly, you can try the following solution:

- Add validations or checks to the style component:

> Code: [blue_print_pos](https://pub.dev/packages/blue_print_pos)
>
> ```
> receiptText.addText(
>  '${invoiceCard.name}',
>  alignment: defaultEnLang ? ReceiptAlignment.left : ReceiptAlignment.right,
> );
> ```

or

> Code: [esc_pos_utils](https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_utils)
>
> ```
> bytes += ticket.textEncoded(
>  '${invoiceCard.name}',
>  styles: PosStyles(
>    align: defaultEnLang ? PosAlign.left : PosAlign.right,
>    bold: true,
>  ),
> );
> ```

The boolean value of `defaultEnLang` is retrieved based on the current language.

**Expected Output:**
[image: Invoice]
I am managing it with styling.

---

### Update 2023:

Some useful Flutter SDKs for Thermal Printer which provides Arabic language support:

- [bluetooth_thermal_printer](https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth_thermal_printer) - This is a Flutter plugin that allows you to use a Bluetooth thermal printer on an Android device.
- [blue_print_pos](https://pub.dev/packages/blue_print_pos) - This is a Flutter plugin that enables you to use a POS (point of sale) system on both Android and iOS devices.
  This is the updated forked [blue_print_pos SDK](https://github.com/ankush-ppie/blue_print_pos/) which I used in Dec 2022. You can use it without facing any issues.

Comment: whats value of encodedCode

Comment: @SHEBIN Replace `encodedCode` with your desired String, I am updating the code format